# Why is the derivative of the binormal vector parallel to the normal vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, parametrization, arc-length

In my notes, it says to consider an arc length parameterization **r**(s). Then we can show that **B'** points in the direction of **N** such that we can write **B'**=-**N**. I understand why ||**B'**||= but am unsure how to show why **B'** is parallel to **N**? Also, is the minus sign just for convention or is there a reason it is there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What can you use to measure angle between vectors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\vt{\mathbf{T}}
\def\vn{\mathbf{N}}
\def\vb{\mathbf{B}}
\def\vr{\mathbf{r}}$In what follows differentiation with respect to arc length is indicated with a prime. 
We have 
\begin{align*}
\vt &= \vr' \\
\vn &= \vt'/\|\vt'\| \\
\vb &= \vt\times\vn.
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
\vb' &= \vt'\times\vn+\vt\times\vn' \\
&= \|\vt'\|\underbrace{\vn\times\vn}_{\mathbf{0}} + \vt\times\vn' \\
&= \vt\times\vn'.
\end{align*}
Note that $\vb$ is orthogonal to $\vt$ by definition of the cross product. 
Since $\|\vb\|=1$, $\vb'$ is also orthogonal to $\vb$. 
(Proof: $(\vb\cdot\vb)' = 2\vb\cdot\vb' = 0$.) 
Since $\vt,\vn,\vb$ form an orthogonal basis, it must be the case that $\vb'$ is proportional to $\vn$. 
We take 
$\vb' = -\tau\vn$. 
The minus sign is a convention. 
It is a version of the right-hand rule. 
Note that $\tau>0$ indicates a twisting of the coordinate frame about the $\vt$ axis in a right-handed manner. 
(Take your right hand and point your thumb in the $\vt$ direction. 
Twist your hand about this axis in the direction in which your fingers are pointing. 
This twist corresponds to $\tau>0$.)

Comment: Ah thank you this makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: I am glad to help!